# Bokeh attribute update doesn't update Model without removing a model from curdoc

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

The below code is a minimal example of an issues where a bokeh model doesn't update when it's attribute is set via a callback. I've found that removing and adding back a model object (not even the suspect one) from the layout of the curdoc forces it to refresh. I've shown this via the first button press.

**Is there a more elegant way to force bokeh to redraw the figure?**

The example is for DataTable.columns.formatter, but I've noticed that this applies to other model attributes as well (including axis ranges, where I've seen a workaround involving setting the range explicitly at figure creation to allow updates).

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown, RadioButtonGroup, CheckboxGroup, \
    Toggle, DataTable, TableColumn, NumberFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, layout


def update_format(attr, old, new):
    if toggle_commas.active == 1:
        (t.columns[1].formatter)
        # remove the commas
        t.columns[1].formatter = NumberFormatter(format='0,0.[00]')
        # show that it updates the actual attribute
        print(t.columns[1].formatter)
        del doc_layout.children[-1]
        doc_layout.children.insert(1, toggle_commas)
    else:
        # change the formatter back and note that it doesn't update the table unless you remove and add something
        (t.columns[1].formatter)
        # remove the commas
        t.columns[1].formatter = NumberFormatter(format='0.[00]')
        # show that it updates the actual attribute
        print(t.columns[1].formatter)

table_data = dict(
        percentiles=['min', '1st', '5th', '10th', '25th', '50th',
                     '75th', '90th', '95th', '99th', 'max', '', 'mean', 'std'],
        values=[i for i in range(1000, 1014)]
    )
table_source = ColumnDataSource(table_data)
table_columns = [
    TableColumn(field="percentiles", title="Percentile"),
    TableColumn(field="values", title="Value", formatter=NumberFormatter(format='0.[00]'))
    ]

t = DataTable(source=table_source, columns=table_columns, width=400, height=600,
              name='pct_table')

toggle_commas = Toggle(label='Commas', active=False)
toggle_commas.on_change('active', update_format)

doc_layout = layout(t, toggle_commas)
curdoc().add_root(doc_layout)
```